Amazon Linux2023のyum.confが機能しない
/etc/yum.confのproxy設定が効きません
環境

AWS環境
プライベートサブネットで動作
NATインスタンスを立ち上げproxy経由でインターネット接続
OS: Amazon Linux 2023(20240401 UpdateのAMI)
yumのバージョン: 4.14.0

やろうとしたこと

proxy経由でDatadog Agentをインストールしようとした
ただしDatadog Agentに限った話ではないと認識しておりますので例として受け取っていただきたいです。

やったこと

/etc/profile.d/proxy.shに以下を追加

export HTTP_PROXY='http://proxy-url.com:<port>'
export HTTPS_PROXY='http://proxy-url.com:<port>'
export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
export http_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}
export NO_PROXY='localhost,169.254.169.254'
export no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}

proxyを有効化
source /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh


/etc/yum.confに以下を追加

[main]
proxy=http://proxy-url.com:<port>


datadog-agentのインストール

$ DD_API_KEY=XXXX DD_SITE="ap1.datadoghq.com" bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script_agent7.sh)"

このタイミングでproxyが効いておらずタイムアウトしました。
install_script_agent7.shの中ではyum installが行われているようです。
yumのインストール先はhttps://yum.datadoghq.com/stable/7/x86_64/です。
/etc/yum.repos.d/datadog.repoに以下が自動で格納されます。
[datadog]
name=Datadog, Inc.
baseurl=https://yum.datadoghq.com/stable/7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://keys.datadoghq.com/hogehoge...

Amazon Linux2 (yumのバージョンは3.4.3)では同じ手順でインストール完了いたしました。
おそらくAmazon Linux2023独特,またはyum4.14.0独特の挙動ではないかと考えているのですが、yum.confの設定を有効にする方法が知りたいです。
ご知見のある方何卒よろしくお願いします。

AL2013 からパッケージ管理は dnf コマンドを使用します。yum も引き続き使えはしますが、この辺りから調べてみて下さい。 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/linux/al2023/ug/package-management.html

/etc/dnf/dnf.confにproxyの設定を追加することで解決いたしました。
回答ありがとうございました！

コメントで解決したようなので改めて回答として記録しておきます。

Amazon Linux 2023 で OS のパッケージ管理は yum コマンドではなく dnf コマンドを使用します。
パッケージ管理ツール - Amazon Linux 2023

Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023) では、デフォルトのソフトウェアパッケージ管理ツールは DNF です。 DNFは AL2 のパッケージ管理ツールである YUM の後継です。
DNF の使い方は YUM と似ています。多くの DNF コマンドは YUM コマンドと同じで、オプションも同じです。コマンドラインインターフェイス (CLI) のコマンドでは、ほとんどの場合、dnf が yum に置き換えられます。

まだ完全には切り替わっておらず、従来の yum コマンドも使えてしまいますが、オプションの設定先を /etc/yum.conf ではなく /etc/dnf/dnf.conf に記載してみてください。
なお、同じ rpm ベースの RHEL 8 においては /etc/yum.conf は /etc/dnf/dnf.conf へのシンボリックリンクになっていました。
